# What is the best way to get XML data to multiple SSIS Data Flow Tasks?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

This is a question on how to structure an SSIS package to solve a very specific problem (I'm new SSIS and have not found anything on the correct approach).

My Problem: I have a SSIS package that reads a very simple XML file. The XML Source sees the information as a single table. One of the table columns is a qualifier that affects the way a record is processed. Rather than having the processing for all of the qualifiers in a single task, I’d like to have a separate task for each qualifier (for modularity). I could have the task for each qualifier read, shred, and process the XML file, but reading and shredding the XML file multiple times seems like an inefficient way of doing this. I’d think it would be better to have a task for an XML Source that persists the data, and then have that data used by a number of other tasks that process the data.

A Possible Solution: From what I’ve read, the correct approach is to save the data into a Raw File Destination, and then to have the various tasks use a Raw File Source. This seems too much like a global variable to me. Is there a better way? I can figure out the specifics, so I don’t need a detailed answer, just the best approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SSIS Conditional Split transformation for this.  It can evaluate your "Qualifier" column and send specified instances down different paths within that Data Flow Task.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137886.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike, but that is what I do not want to do. That puts a lot of code in a single task, making it hard to read and not very modular. What I would like to learn is how to best structure an SSIS package so that I don't end up with large tasks that go off-screen. It is straight forward to do this in most programming languages by factoring code in a rational way. I suspect that SSIS is oriented towards saving data to disk rather than persisting data in memory because it is used to deal with large sets of data.

Comment: Mate you are in for a world of pain if you try to bring "modular" and "rational" programming ideas into SSIS.  It just wasn't put together like that.  Assuming you can get over that, my proposal would have all the logic in a single transformation object, so you wouldn't have to worry about it going "off-screen".  Also SSIS is definitely oriented to memory over disk - I've been working with it for almost a decade and have never needed a Raw file yet.

Comment: Thanks again. I was beginning to suspect what you said. I bought a very thick reference book on SSIS, and didn't see much in there about modularity. I also haven't seen much on the web, only using Raw Files, and Script Components as Recordset Sources.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that there is a way of factoring a DFT (Data Flow Task) designed into SSIS. SSIS is structured so the each DFT provides a complete ETL function. The only way to "factor" a DFT seems to be to create an ad hoc data flow in the Control Flow by using Raw File sources and destinations to fake DFT input and output parameters. This means creating and managing lots of files (and variables for the file names). Recordset sources and destinations can also be used, but the coding overhead might be higher (I haven’t tried using Recordsets, only Raw Files).

Not being able to factor DFTs makes creating and validating complex SSIS packages extremely difficult. Microsoft really needs to come up with a solution. I found another use case in a web forum, being able to recover a task without having to go all of the way back to the beginning. I’ll add a link to that post here if I can find it again.

One solution might be to allow a DFT to execute another DFT, just as a package can execute another package in the control flow. This breaks the convention that each DFT provides a complete ETL function, but if this is the best way the benefit of being able to factor DFTs outweighs any added conceptual complexity.

Disclaimer: I am an experienced LabVIEW programmer, so my view of dataflow is likely biased. I could be missing an obvious solution.